# Magento 2.4.4 Page Builder Row Not Working

Tags: magento2

We recently updated to 2.4.4 and we've since noticed that the "row" page builder section is no longer working.

When dragging the "row" section in a JS error is triggered:

```
Unable to load preview component (Magento_PageBuilder/js/content-type/row/preview) for row. Please check preview component exists and content type configuration is correct.
```

I've looked through other questions on Stack Overflow and cannot find anyone hitting the same problem.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is due to module-page-builder being updated for Magento 2.4.5 but this does not seem to be backwards compatible with 2.4.4 from what I have experienced.

Run `composer require magento/module-page-builder:2.2.2` from your Magento root directory to bring the correct version in and I recommend you remove this require when upgrading past 2.4.4.

Answer (score 0):

Below command worked for me from Magento root directory

```
composer require magento/module-page-builder:2.2.2 --with-all-dependencies
```

Use the option --with-all-dependencies (-W) to allow upgrades, downgrades and removals for packages currently locked to specific versions.

After above command, executed below commands

```
php bin/magento indexer:reindex
php bin/magento setup:upgrade
php bin/magento setup:static-content:deploy -f
php bin/magento cache:flush
```